# StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer recommended configuration

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the lock functionality (LockTake and LockRelease) in StackExchange.Redis, but need to keep it basically constantly polling.  I have it sleeping for a random interval from 0 to 10ms and then trying again.  I'd bet this basically ties up the connection.

The documentation I found suggests to (almost) always use only 1 ConnectionMultiplexer, which will only make 1 connection to Redis, but I also believe that recommendation is due to the expected availability on that connection.  I have at most say 125 potential threads that could need to call Redis simultaneously.  I could use a connection pool, but how many ConnectionMultiplexers should be in the pool given this scenario?

**Edit**

After discussion with Marc in comments below, switching to Pub/Sub, but still using connection pool, here's the code:

Here's the TakeLock method

```
private Task TakeLockAsync(string key, string value)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        var task = taskCompletionSource.Task;
        var db = _dbFactory.GetDatabase();
        //if we can get the lock, do it and return
        bool gotLockTry1 = db.LockTake(key, value, _redisLockConfig.RedisLockMaxAgeTimeSpan);
        if (gotLockTry1)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
            return task;
        }

        // if we failed to get the lock, 
        // set up a subscriber to listen for lock release publish
        var subscriber = db.Multiplexer.GetSubscriber();
        Action<RedisChannel, RedisValue> handler = null;
        handler = (redisChannel, redisValue) =>
        {
            bool gotLockTry3 = db.LockTake(key, value, _redisLockConfig.RedisLockMaxAgeTimeSpan);
            if (gotLockTry3)
            {
                subscriber.Unsubscribe(_subscriptionChannelName, handler);
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
            }
        };
        subscriber.Subscribe(_subscriptionChannelName, handler);

        // double check to make sure a release didn't come through while subscribing
        bool gotLockTry2 = db.LockTake(key, value, _redisLockConfig.RedisLockMaxAgeTimeSpan);
        if (gotLockTry2)
        {
            subscriber.Unsubscribe(_subscriptionChannelName, handler);
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
            return task;
        }
        return task;
    }
```

and the Dispose:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value))
        {
            return;
        }

        var db = _dbFactory.GetDatabase();

        //nested transactions not allowed, so can't call LockReleaseAsync
        var trans = db.CreateTransaction();
        // http://redis.io/topics/distlock
        // remove the key only if it exists and the value matches key's value
        trans.AddCondition(Condition.StringEqual(_key, _value));
        trans.KeyDeleteAsync(_key);
        trans.PublishAsync(_subscriptionChannelName, "something else here");
        //runs only when execute called
        trans.Execute();
    }
```

Comment: I wonder whether pub/sub might be the way to go here. So a longer interval between polls *or* activation viapub/sub, whichever comes first. Obviously with a "pub" from the code that is releasing the lock. Could that work for you?

Comment: @MarcGravell I had actually attempted that earlier, but had issues with it.  It turned out we had a cluster of redis servers behind a load balancer instead of master/slave cluster, so it'd probably work just fine now.  Do you have a guess as to how many connections I'd need using just the polling though?  Maybe just the order of magnitude (10 or 100)?

Comment: @MarcGravell I switched my redis lock to use pub/sub.  I created an endpoint that does the lock, then has a half second sleep inside it.  When running this using 1 ConnectionMultiplexer, it hangs.  It actually failed to delete the key, though I'm not sure why.  When I increase the connections to 10, it works just fine.  I'm going with the pub/sub with 10 connections (per machine, 40 total) if I don't hear from you, but would love to get your advice.

Comment: I'd need to see some pseudocode to comment on the hangs. As for the polling.... It depends how many things are polling in parallel. Even if one thread is looping, thst doesn't block other threads from using the mixer, although it will increase server and network load. It might still be fine one 1. But I wonder if a better idea is for me to think about a better / supportable way of doing this and embedding it in the library.

Comment: @MarcGravell I edited my question to include code.  I'd argue for a connection pool built in before I would for this pub/sub locking mechanism, though.